# Equivalent Function To the lamda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, sorting

I have this list.

```
a = ["1.dat", "3.dat", "2.dat", "4.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]
```

I wanted to sort this list like,

```
['1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', '4.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '9.dat', '15.dat', '21.dat', '25.dat']
```

So I have tried this and it worked.

```
a.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
print(a)
```

My question is what is the equivalent user defined function to this `lamda` function?

Comment: Your two lists are not the same - a bit confusing

Comment: sorry for the wrong code. Now it's edited. @Stefan

Comment: lambda *is* a user defined function, but this is just `def _unamed(item): return (len(item, item))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any lambda in Python is structured like this:

```
lambda <optional parameters>: <return value expression>
```

So, to rewrite a lambda as a normal user-defined function, you can simply:

```
def function_name(<optional parameters>):
    return <return value expression>
```

In your case:

```
lambda item: (len(item), item)
```

Becomes:

```
def key_func(item):
    return len(item), item
```

Note that the parentheses aren't required in this case.

And so your sorting code becomes:

```
a.sort(key=key_func)
print(a)
```

Test with your data:

```
a = ["1.dat", "3.dat", "2.dat", "4.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]


def key_func(item):
    return len(item), item


a.sort(key=key_func)
print(a)
```

The `.sort()` function takes the function provided as `key` and calls it for every element of the list, passing that element to the `key` function and using the return value as a sorting key.

Comment: Why actually parameters are not required here? how is it getting the length of x without knowing the parameter value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. The function `key_func` takes a string `item` as argument and returns the length of that string `len(item)` and the string itself `item`, just like your lambda did. Since that tuple of values starts with the length, your `a` ends up sorted by length first and name second. What do you mean by `x` and why do you think `key_func` or `sort()` wouldn't have access to the length of each item? I added a brief explanation, perhaps that answers your question?

Comment: My mistake. not x. I was talking about `item`. Sorry for that. My question was how is it assigning the strings to item one by one? As no values are passing to the function `key_func`. And returning back the length of string!

Comment: Ok, I see - see the final remark in my answer. The `.sort()` method on `a` automatically calls `key_func` for every element it wants to know the key of, typically once for each element in the list. Since you're sorting the list, and you passed `key_func` as its `key` parameter it knows to call `key_func` with a single parameter, namely each element of the list in some order depending on the sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a `function` as a `key`

you don't add parenthesis as if you do that means you are running the function if you don't do that means you are initialising the key variable to the function.

basically for any function `xyz()` if I do `a = xyz()` is am storing the output of the function but if I do `a = xyz` I can call xyz as `a()`

we want key to be called by our sort function to get what to sort it to, not store value

```
a = ["1.dat", "3.dat", "2.dat", "4.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]

a.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
print(a)

a = ["1.dat", "3.dat", "2.dat", "4.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]


#THIS IS YOUR FUNCTION
def keyFnc (x):
    return len(x) , x


a.sort(key=keyFnc)
print(a)

a = ["1.dat", "33.dat", "222.dat", "4444.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]

a.sort(key=keyFnc)
print(a)
```

```
['1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', '4.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '9.dat', '15.dat', '21.dat', '25.dat']
['1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', '4.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '9.dat', '15.dat', '21.dat', '25.dat']
['1.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '9.dat', '15.dat', '21.dat', '25.dat', '33.dat', '222.dat', '4444.dat']
```

you can assign variables to a function in python because they are treated as first-class objects

Comment: Well. This one works. But need to how actually is it working? The keyFnc has one parameter but it's not passing any value. And what actually doing it after returning the len(x), x ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define function separately like as given belove

```
a = ["1.dat", "3.dat", "2.dat", "4.dat", "6.dat", "5.dat", "21.dat", "25.dat", "15.dat", "9.dat"]

#a.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
#print(a)
def key_func(x):
    return (len(x),x)

a.sort(key=key_func)
print(a)

#output
#['1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', '4.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '9.dat', '15.dat', '21.dat', '25.dat']
```

try this and let me know if any query

Comment: This doesn't work. "15.dat" is at the end. It should have been after "9.dat".

Comment: try again then let me know @HasibulIslamPolok